# Talis Falling - vs. Leaving the Sukkah

Tags: halacha, tallit-gadol, sukkah

Why is it then when one's Talis falls off unintentionally, he is required to make another blessing (Ashkenaz for sure) as it constitutes an interruption (*hesech hada'as*), but when it comes to Sukkah, if a person was eating cake in the sukkah and went to the bathroom, he would not require a new Bracha **on the Sukka** upon returning to the sukkah?

Why is this any less *hesech hada'as*?

Comment: Did the person accidentally leave the Sukkah? How do you know these rules are true?

Comment: I probably phrased this terribly. Here goes: if one went to the bathroom during davening and he removed his Tallis and tefilin, I believe on his Tallis he would not require a new blessing because in theory he could have worn it there, but in tefilin it would require a new blessing, because he could not have worn them there - thus the bathroom constitutes hesech hadaas. Why isn’t it hesech hadas for sukkah?

Comment: Those seem to me like very different questions. Remember to [edit] your post to clarify what exactly you mean to ask.

Comment: You're assuming that he doesn't have to make a new Bracha (on the Sukka, I assume - and edited into the question).  Can you source that? (It's how we all behave, but who says it's the actual Halacha?)

Comment: Followup question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/91668