# Sukkah vs Tefilin

Tags: tefilin, sukkah

If one is in middle of a meal on Sukkot and that person uses the bathroom, when one returns to his Sukkah, it is my understanding that a new blessing on the sukkah is not required. However, when it comes to wearing tefilin, if one needed to use the restroom, according to the mishna berura, a new blessing would be required because tefilin are forbidden to be worn there and thus it results in a hefsik. Why don’t we apply the same principal to sukkah? If you will say that the bathroom doesn’t constitute an interruption in the meal - It’s forbidden to eat in a bathroom as well.

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88771/

Comment: To be honest - I asked the “related q” - although in hindsight, I don’t know what I was thinking then, I was completely off base.

Comment: As an aside, I wouldn't ask this question about Sukkah - ask about the meal itself.

Comment: Tefilin and sukkah is a Bracha on a mitzvah. A meal is a Bracha in having ha’nah  Not sure if they same rules apply.